# Angular Error when project building since service worker is added

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

Today it is time to implement PWA in my application, I have already done it in some other applications without problem .. but today nothing happens as expected ...
when I launch the construction of the project, during the last step "generation of the html index, the following error appears:

> √ Browser application bundle generation complete.
> √ Copying assets complete.
> √ Index html generation complete.
> × Service worker generation failed.
> Directory import 'C:\Users\Damien\WebstormProjects\diiage\front\node_modules@angular\service-worker\config' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from C:\Users\Damien\WebstormProjects\diiage\front\node_modules@angular-devkit
> \build-angular\src\utils\load-esm.js

and i really have no idea where it is from ...

for information I followed the following tutorial : **https://www.ganatan.com/tutorials/progressive-web-app-avec-angular** and my files are compatible with those of the tutorial.

I hope you will be able to help me, **in any case I thank you in advance**

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution .. I updated my project .. (ng update) ...